# Изменение класса кнопки при нажатии

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть скрипт. Самое привлекательное в нем - простота. Нажатием кнопки показываем/скрываем содержимое дива. Это работает.

```
// JS
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_hide(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if(div.style.display == 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>

// HTML
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide('key1')" class="no">
<div id="key1" style="display:none">
слово
</div>
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы у input'а при нажатии менялся класс, т.е. изначально класс="no", при нажатии, чтобы менялся на "yes", при следующем нажатии снова обратно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно также, как вы делаете с `div.style.display`, только пишете `div.className` ну и `no yes` вместо `block none`.

Да, а чтобы не передавать и не делать айдюк к импуту, создайте функцию которая будет принимать this:

```
...
function changeClass(div)
{
   ....
   div.className ... //не надо делать поиск по айди
}
...
<input ... onclick="changeClass(this);" ... />
...
```

Comment: Можно не писать еще одну функцию, а в текущую передать this и дописать проверку

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Да, конечно. Я обрисовал общую схему, с акцентом на то что this - это текущий элемент, и не сложилось впечатление что это может заменить id в текущей функции

Comment: Удаляем класс

    var input, // ссылка на импут
    classname; // значение класса (Yes)
    if(input.className.match(new RegExp(classname))
       input.className = input.className.replace(new RegExp(classname),'');

Добавляем класс

    var input, // ссылка на импут
    classname; // значение класса (Yes)
    if(!input.className.match(new RexExp(classname))
       input.className += ' ' + classname;

Comment: за этот код тоже спасибо